# Implementing Centralized Hotkey Handling/Processing

Tags: c#, .net, hotkeys, imessagefilter

I'm working on a project where I need to implement customizable hotkeys across the application.  There are a number of different forms and user controls that need to implement different subsets of hotkeys.  I would like to implement all of the handling and processing in a central MessageFilter class.

I want to have a base class that has methods for all hotkeys, and then just override the subset of needed ones in each form/control, but I can't figure out how to have all of the forms and usercontrols share a base class.  This would allow me to do something like this to process the hotkeys:

`public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)

{

    HotKeyAction action = GetActionForKey(keydata);

    BaseClass instance = GetBaseClassFromFocusedFormOrControl();

    switch (action)

    {

        case HotKeyAction.Action1: instance.Action1() break;

    }

}`

Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create forms as a "base class" so to speak.  That is, you could create a Form called ShanesForm with nothing on it.  Place your method calls in this form, and then set that form as the base class to all your other forms.